# Question from a high school student about role of natural sciences?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science

I am doing my essay on natural sciences methodology therefore, I wanted to give the example how according to the scientific method, new valid evidence could add to or correct previous knowledge. However, can I talk about physics how Newton was able to find the law of gravity using classical physics but Einstein was able to contradict this claim by adding on or correcting that this might not work at the speeds of light. Does this show the fact that new information can replace new information?

Let me know and please be nice, it is my first year in philosophy.

Comment: "Contradict" might not be the right word to use: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/52168/195139

Comment: Thank you very much @Sandejo , in my essay the idea is that I would tell what science methodology is (features, etc) then gave the example of both quantum and classical mechanics. However, I have to talk about a counter-argument. Would cosmology and  the multiverse universe be a good example to show although it is doesn’t follow the scientific method, it is still scientifically verified? Please let me know what you think, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you might benefit from this UPitt https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_GR_geometry/Einstein_on_Kant.html you can browse around on Prof Norton’s pages there.